# Why is there segmentation fault in this merge sort?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, mergesort, buffer-overrun

I compiled this code on different compilers, but all of them gave runtime error. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```cpp
void merge(int *str, int beg, int mid, int end) {
    int *arr = new int[end - beg + 1];
    int k = 0;
    int i = beg;
    int j = mid + 1;

    while (i <= mid && j <= end) {
        if (str[i] < str[j]) {
            arr[k] = str[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = str[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid) {
        arr[k] = str[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j <= end) {
        arr[k] = str[j];
        //here i got buffer overrun while writing to arr
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for (i = beg; i <= end; i++) {
        str[i] = arr[i - beg];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}

void merge_sort(int *str, int beg, int end) {
    
    if (beg >= end)
        return;

    int mid = (end - beg) / 2;
    merge_sort(str, beg, mid);
    merge_sort(str, mid + 1, end);
    merge(str, beg, mid, end);
}
```

This code is almost same as I found on Sanfoundry, but that one is working but mine got some errors.

Comment: Protip: Instead of this `int* arr = new int[end - beg + 1];` use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I assume you're implementing merge-sort as a learning exercise (which is fine, otherwise I'd be telling you to use `<algorithm>`'s `std::merge` premade implementation) - is that the case? Anyway, you should be using `size_t` instead of `int` to represent offsets and indexes - not least because it helps prevent confusing `int` _data_ values with their _incomparable_ offset values.

Comment: `int mid = (end - beg) / 2;` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computation of the mid point in `merge_sort` is incorrect: instead of `int mid = (end - beg) / 2;` you should write:

```
    int mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
```

Note also that your API is confusing as `mid` seems to be the end of the index of the last element of the left half and `end` the index of the last element of the right slice.  It is much simpler and less error prone to specify `mid` as the index of the first element of the right half and `end` the index of the first element **after** the right slice. With this convention, the initial call is:

```
    merge_sort(array, 0, array_length);
```

Here is a modified version using type `size_t` for index and length variables:

```
void merge(int *str, size_t beg, size_t mid, size_t end) {
    int *arr = new int[end - beg];
    size_t i = beg;
    size_t j = mid;
    size_t k = 0;

    while (i < mid && j < end) {
        if (str[i] <= str[j]) {
            arr[k++] = str[i++];
        } else {
            arr[k++] = str[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < mid) {
        arr[k++] = str[i++];
    }
    while (j < end) {
        arr[k++] = str[j++];
    }
    for (i = beg; i < end; i++) {
        str[i] = arr[i - beg];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}

void merge_sort(int *str, size_t beg, size_t end) {
    if (end - beg >= 2) {
        size_t mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
        merge_sort(str, beg, mid);
        merge_sort(str, mid, end);
        merge(str, beg, mid, end);
    }
}
```